# Azure Functions - File not found

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm following this guide to get Azure Functions installed and creating an app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

When I run the command `func init MyFunctionProj` I should get an output like this:

```
Writing .gitignore
Writing host.json
Writing local.settings.json
Created launch.json
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Code/Playground/MyFunctionProj/.git/
```

But instead I get this:

```
Writing .gitignore
Writing host.json
Writing local.settings.json
Writing C:\Users\nahue\dev\MyFunctionProj\.vscode\extensions.json
El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

Translation: "File not found".

I've already installed all the things mentioned in the link and it doesn't work. It creates that folder called ".vscode" with that "extensions.json" file inside and it doesn't create "launch.json", I don't know why. I don't have Visual Studio nor VS Code installed in my computer.

Comment: What version of Azure Functions Core Tools and what version of Function Runtime Version are you running? Just run `func` and it will tell you.

Comment: Hi Johan, I tried using Azure Functions Core Tools (1.0.12) with Function Runtime Version: 1.0.11702.0 and Azure Functions Core Tools (220.0.0-beta.0) with Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11651.0 but it doesn't work in none of those combinations.

Comment: Update: I followed the instructions in my brother's computer and it worked. Could it be related to an installation of Visual Studio 2015 I made months ago? I still cannot make it work in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init result in [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#create-a-local-functions-project) is for v1.x. On my side(v2.x), I also see `.vscode\extensions.json` instead of `launch.json`.

As for the `File not found` issue, please make sure you have installed [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on your computer.

I get the output before I install it:

```
Writing .gitignore
Writing host.json
Writing local.settings.json
Writing C:\Users\jerryliu\myfunc\.vscode\extensions.json
unable to find git on the path
```

After:

```
Writing .gitignore
Writing host.json
Writing local.settings.json
Writing C:\Users\jerryliu\myfunc\.vscode\extensions.json
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/jerryliu/myfunc/.git/
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for answering. I have installed Git, I thought it was a problem with Git too so I even downloaded the latest version but it keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: @Nahue Have you checked whether your system path has git location?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll check it when I get home!

Comment: I checked it and yes, it has the git location.

Comment: Assume you use windows cmd to run `func init`, make sure `git.exe` is under the folder specified by system path. Then directly use `git init` command in any folder to see whether it works. If you don't see output like `Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/jerryliu/Desktop/.git/`, it means git is not correctly installed. If the command does works, check common issue for windows10. [Reference link](https://www.easeus.com/resource/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified.html).

Comment: I followed the instructions and Installed some updates for Windows and it worked! Thank you very much Jerry!